# How to paste a function over a word to wrap it? (vim)

Tags: vim, paste

Is it possible to yank a function and paste it over a word such that it adopts that word as a parameter? For example if I have

```
def foo(name):
    pass

"John"
```

Is there any way I can paste `foo` onto `"John"` so as to get `foo("John")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. You can use macros like these:

```
Yank:  <Esc>`<"ayf(f)"by`>
Paste: B"aPE"bp
```

Lets unwrap them. The *Yank* macro assumes you have the function selected and performs the following actions:

1. `<Esc>` - cancel current selection
2. `` `< `` - move to the start of last selection
3. `"ayf(` - yank text up to and including the opening parenthesis into register "a"
4. `f)` - move to the closing parenthesis
5. `"by'>` - yank everything up to the end of last selection into register "b"

The *Paste* macro is much simpler:

1. `B` - move to the beginning of the current word
2. `"aP` - paste contents of register "a" in front of the current position
3. `E` - move to the end of the current word
4. `"bp` paste contents of register "b" after the current position

Comment: I can actually wrap my head around that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one off thing, you could just use a macro:

```
:map q 0ifoo(^vESCA)^vESC
```

Just hit "q" on each line you want to change.
If the word is not on a line by itself you'll have to be a bit cleverer.

Comment: The problem with vim is that you have to know everything before you unlock its true potential http://www.ende-der-vernunft.org/files/joern/20090110-lernkurveng.jpg

Comment: You can't know everything about vim. It's a never-ending learning process. :)